# Show/Hide doesn't work unless page is refreshed

Tags: javascript, jquery

**EDIT:** for clarity purposes, I've edited this question.
**EDIT 2:** I was able to solve half of my issue.

Below is a simple script for users to delete the pictures they uploaded.

Depending on whether or not there is an image saved in the database. A toggle OR an upload icon should show.

**The issue is** that when the delete button is clicked, the picture  and the toggle buttons get removed BUT the upload icon won't show (unless page is refreshed).

```
if (image exists in database) { 

   <div class="toggle" id="toggle<?php echo $image_id ?>"></div>
 }      
 else {
    <div class="upload_icon"  id="upload<?php echo $image_id ?>"></div>
      }

`SQL query to select image in database` 

 //this DIV expands when the toggle button is clicked

 <div class="content" id="image<?php echo $image_id ?>"><img src="<?php echo 
 $path ?>" />  
    <div class="remove content"><a href="#" id="<?php echo $image_id ?>"   
    class="delete_icon">Remove!</a></div>
 </div>
```

Javascript part:

```
$(function(){
$('.delete_icon').on("click",function() 
{
var ID = $(this).attr("id");
var dataString = 'image_id='+ ID;
$this = $(this);
if(confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this image ?"))
{
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "delete.php",
data: dataString,
cache: false,
success: function(html){

$('#image'+ID).remove()
$('#toggle'+ID).remove()
$('#upload'+ID).show();
});
}
return false;
});
});
```

What am I missing here ?

Answer (score 1):

`this` is no longer the link once you're inside the context of the `success` function. I saved off `this` and used it inside, that should do the trick.

Also I'm not sure that the `find` is actually going to work. Based on your example I'm not sure that `#toggle` elements are actualy nested within `.delete_icon`.

If they aren't you might want to do `$('#toggle'+ID)` rather than using find. It's an ID selector anyway so it wouldn't be affecting performance.

```
$(function(){
  $('.delete_icon').on("click",function() {

    var ID = $(this).attr("id"),
        dataString = 'image_id='+ ID,
        $this = $(this);

    if( confirm("Are you sure you want to remove this image ?") ) {
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "delete.php",
        data: dataString,
        cache: false,
        success: function(html) {

          $this.closest(".content").hide();

          $('#toggle'+ID).hide()

          $('#upload'+ID).show();

        }
      });
    }
    return false;
  });
});
```

Comment: Added a couple more questions in the code, if this doesn't work for you.

Comment: thanks a lot for your quick reply ! yes, var $content = $(".content").hide(); is intended: once the pic is deleted, it also hides the pictures that were toggled. Otherwise the deleted pic is erased from the database, but the pic is still visible unless you refresh the page.   .upload_icon and .toggle are not inside of the "content" div. As of now, i tried your code, and it still doesn't work...

Comment: Tweaked it. I think that'l do the trick for you, as long as `.content` is the parent of `.delete_icon` ... otherwise you should make it an `ID`. You don't want to just do `$('.content').hide()` since that can hit all your content divs at once

Comment: Also you should console log what it's about to `show` and `hide` to see if that's hitting what you want.. or if any of them are blank.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I just edited my question to make it clearer. The issue is that once the picture gets deleted, the #toggle and #upload buttons should switch, and they don't (unless the page is refreshed). I've upvoted your answer though.

Comment: Can you `console.log` in the success function and tell me if it's finding the elemnts you mean to show or hide?